# Coding Game in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, game-engine

I'm trying to develop some game in `winform C#`.But there is some problem that make me compressed.First of all if I need to talk about my game,it is going to be kind of a `car race`.There are boxes on two lines.They get closer and car tries to avoid them with jumping or changing its direction(right or left).I can generate boxes regulary,make car jump turn left and right so far.Here is my codes so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace windowsForApplication15
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        right,
        left,
        up,
        down
    }

    private Directions car_direction;

    //value for fall speed
    int G = 15;
    int force;

    //determines wheather car is gonna jump or not
    bool jump;



    //boxes from right
    public PictureBox[] right_matrix = new PictureBox[5];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        jump = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// timer for controlling car
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to creating 5 boxes
        create_box(5);

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //if jump is true
        if (jump)
        {
            //start falling
            car.Top -= force;
            force -= 1;
        }
        //being able to stay top of block(I couldun't make my car stay specific point when falling is stop so created a block ,which is transparent in my winform 
        //so car can stop when faling is finish)
        if (car.Left + car.Width - 1 > block.Left && car.Left + car.Width + 5 < block.Left + block.Width + car.Width
            && car.Top + car.Height >= block.Top && car.Top < block.Top)
        {
            car.Top = panel1.Height - block.Height - car.Height;
            force = 0;
            jump = false;
        }


    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && car_direction != Directions.right)
        {
            car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X + 130, car.Location.Y);
            car_direction = Directions.right;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && car_direction != Directions.left)
        {
            car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X - 130, car.Location.Y);
            car_direction = Directions.left;
        }

        if (!jump && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            jump = true;
            force = G;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// craeting boxes,which are gonne be what want to avoid from
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    private void create_box(int value)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <= value; i++)

        {
            int number = rnd.Next(0, 7);
            PictureBox boxes_right = new PictureBox();
            panel1.Controls.Add(boxes_right);
            boxes_right.Width = 50;
            boxes_right.Height = 15;
            boxes_right.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            boxes_right.Top = (i * 20) + 152;
            boxes_right.Left = 312;
            right_matrix[i] = boxes_right;
            right_matrix[i].Visible = true;

            switch (number)
            {
                case 1:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.Brown;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.MistyRose;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    boxes_right.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// it is used to controlling boxes movement
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random rastgele = new Random();

        //shifting boxes aganist bottom of form.
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            int number_2 = rastgele.Next(0, 7);
            right_matrix[i].Top += (right_matrix[i].Top / 28) - 2;

            right_matrix[i].Width += +1;

            //if collision is true 
            if (Collision(right_matrix[i], car))
            {
                //stop application
                Application.Exit();
            }

            //if box  touches the block
            if (right_matrix[i].Bottom > block.Top + 25)
            {
                //make it be in from the top
                right_matrix[i].Top = 152;
                right_matrix[i].Width = 50;
                right_matrix[i].Height = 15;

                //for changing boxes color
                switch (number_2)
                {
                    case 1:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.Pink;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.Brown;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.MistyRose;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        right_matrix[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
                        break;
                }
            }


        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To finish game when car crushes box
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Object1"></param>
    /// <param name="Object2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool Collision(dynamic Object1, dynamic Object2)
    {

        bool Collided = false;
        if (Object1.Top + Object1.Height <= Object2.Top + 5 & Object1.Top + Object1.Height >= Object2.Top & Object1.Left == Object2.Left)
        {
            if (Object1.Visible == true & Object2.Visible == true & jump == false)


            {
                Collided = true;
            }
        }

        return Collided;
    }


}
}
```

1. Collision is not working even if I press left,right or top
   button once
2. I should generate boxes irregularly to save that game from boredom.

Comment: `Object1.Left == Object2.Left` is not good enough. You need to check the whole rectangles of both objects, since they aren't just points.

Comment: What do "Collision is not working even if I press left,right or top button once" & "I should generate boxes irregularly to save that game from boredom." mean? What's working? What's not? What should it be doing? What is it doing? What you've written isn't enough.

Comment: There are a lot of resources about collision detection. Have a look at this for example [Simple Collision Detection](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/articles/vb-net/simple-collision-detection/)

Comment: Pikoh thanks a lot :) I solved my problem about collision

Comment: @GulcanYanik you should post what you did to solve your problem as an answer to help those who might be having the same problem in the future.

Comment: I will when I am done:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `MetricSet` `class`, which would have a description of metric rules. This class should have a `collide(MetricSet otherSet)` `bool` method. You should also have a generic solution to be able to define shapes as `MetricSet`s and implement the particularities for `Rectangle` (for now). This is far more superior than solving particularly the problem for your rectangles, because you will have other shapes in the future as well.